# Change detection in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular2.0 component:

```
import {Component, View, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'font-size-component',
  properties: ['fontSize'],
  events: ['fontSizeChanged']
})
@View({
  template: `<input id="fontSize" [(ng-model)]="fontSize"/>`,
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class FontSizeComponent {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Now, I want this component to trigger an event (using event-binding) when the input changes.

On Angular 1.X I had several options (`ng-change` or `$scope.$wacth`). I am looking for a similar solution, so when the input changes I will be able to use `eventemitter` and trigger an `fontSizeChanged` event.

Thanks,

Yaniv

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. You can use javascript [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). So your component would look like:

```js
import {Component, View, FORM_DIRECTIVES, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'font-size-component',
    properties: ['fontSize'],
    events:     ['fontSizeChange']
})
@View({
    template: `
        <input id="fontSize" [(ng-model)]="fontSizeModel"/>
    `,
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class FontSizeComponent {
    fontSize: string;
    fontSizeChange = new EventEmitter();

    get fontSizeModel() {
        return this.fontSize;
    }

    set fontSizeModel(value) {
        this.fontSizeChange.next(value);
    }
}
```

Check out [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jFqJlM2JnQnKNeQYZKBr?p=preview)

2. Slightly different solution is to use `(input)` event binding:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'font-size-component',
    properties: ['fontSize'],
    events:     ['fontSizeChange']
})
@View({
    template: `
        <input 
          id="fontSize" 
          [value]="fontSize" 
          (input)="fontSizeChange.next($event.target.value)"
        />
    `,
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class FontSizeComponent {
    fontSize: string;
    fontSizeChange = new EventEmitter();
}
```

See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HRa5lVU0npIWkaj1SAUW?p=preview)

Comment: Wow - this is an **awesome** answer, thank you very much!! One question - in your first example I cannot see how can I initial the input with the incoming "fontSize" (attribute binding) data. Regarding the second example - is `(input)` equivalent to `ng-change()` (that I was looking for (:

Comment: You helped me a-lot - Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `fontSizeChange.next` is deprecated, please use `fontSizeChange.emit` instead.

Comment: In the meantime `properties` were changed to `input` and `events` to `output`

Comment: This is a more recent example very similar to the first one that helped me--the important part was the `@Input` only on `setter`:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-setter

Answer (score 18):

You could also tap into the lifecycle hooks of Angular2. From the documentation:

> ngOnChanges(changeRecord) { ... }
>   Called after every change to input properties and before processing content or child views.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Just add this method to your component class:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
  if (changes['fontSize']) { // fire your event }
}
```

The above guide includes a Plunkr for this:
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/lifecycle-hooks/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: This was what I looking for.

Comment: plunkr link dead :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually handle changes to the input you can separate out the short-hand [(ngModel)] by doing something like this:

```
<input id="fontSize" [ngModel]="fontSize" (ngModelChange)="fontSizeChange($event)"/>
```

Make sure that within the `fontSizeChange($event)` function you use the $event to assign the changed input value to the `fontSize` variable as this is no longer automatically handled.

When you use [(ngModel)] it is really doing something like this:

```
<input id="fontSize" [ngModel]="fontSize" (ngModelChange)="fontSize=$event" />
```

For more information you can refer to the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way-binding-with-ngmodel

Currently Angular 2 is still in beta so this is subject to change.